# Is it VL (Linking Verbs) or VT (Transitive Verbs)?

Tags: grammar, transitive-verbs, linking-verbs

Federal Reserve remains patient about next U.S. rate hike.

Is this sentence "linking verb" or "transitive verb"? I think it is VL but not quite sure about it.

Comment: Incidentally, that's not a proper sentence. It looks like a news headline.  It needs at least one, and possibly two "the"s.

Comment: A verb with an adjective is not transitive as an adjective is no direct object. To remain is a linking verb.

Answer (score 1):

It's not transitive.  If it were, you could form the passive [*]"Patient is remained by the Federal Reserve."  But that's no good, so it must be intransitive.  (I'm unenthusiastic about the term "linking verb", but I suppose "remain" would be one.)